# Adding bounty shows two listings on /revisions

Tags: feature-request, bounties, revisions-list, timeline

I started a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27900408/1234256). On [its /revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27900408/revisions), there are **two** entries for this:

[image]

I propose that it look like this instead:

[image]

Comment: There are other ways to add notices (albeit only through moderator actions).